# Can we say 'hold little property'?

Tags: phrases

Can we say this sentence?

> hold little property

I see a sentence in my browser:

> if a couple holds little to property

why don't we say

> if a couple holds little property

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I see a sentence in my browser"?? You can easily look up the word little in a dictionary.

Comment: I don't see a reasonable way to answer this without more details, (and since this is six months old I'm not holding my breath) the sentence in the browser is wrong and the proposed correction is right, but without context, such as the source of this line, no answer is useful.